# ImageView reference not getting updated after Passing Position of RecyclerView To PagerAdapter in order to update ImageView reference

Tags: android

This is CustomAdapter Class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context ctx;View v;
int a[]=    {R.drawable.dbz,R.drawable.fatherandson,R.drawable.gohan,R.drawable.gohanssj,R.drawable.gohanssjb,R.drawable.gokussjb
, R.drawable.gokussjg,R.drawable.songohan,R.drawable.vegitassjb,R.drawable.vegitassjg};
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Button btn;
CustomAdapter(Context ctx){
    this.ctx=ctx;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return a.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view==(RelativeLayout)object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
    v=view;
    ImageView img=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
    btn =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    img.setImageResource(a[position]);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager=WallpaperManager.getInstance(ctx);
              try {
                    wallpaperManager.setResource(a[position]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
}

public void sendPosition(int position) {
    ImageView img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
    Toast.makeText(ctx, ""+a[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    img.setImageResource(a[position]);
}
```

}

This is MainActivity Class

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mDataSet;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomAdapter adapter2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        adapter2=new CustomAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter2);
        mDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        mDataSet.add(R.drawable.formatfactorydbz);
        mDataSet.add(R.drawable.formatfactoryfatherandson);
        mDataSet.add(R.drawable.formatfactorygohan);
        mDataSet.add(R.drawable.formatfactorygohanssj);
        mDataSet.add(R.drawable.formatfactorygohanssjb);
        mDataSet.add(R.drawable.formatfactorygokussjb);
        mDataSet.add(R.drawable.formatfactorygokussjg);
        mDataSet.add(R.drawable.formatfactorysongohan);
        mDataSet.add(R.drawable.formatfactoryvegitassjb);
        mDataSet.add(R.drawable.formatfactoryvegitassjg);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new MainAdapter(mDataSet);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                // do whatever
               adapter2.sendPosition(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                // do whatever
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

I am sending the position of the image by sendPosition Method from MainActivity to CustomAdapter and position value is correct when I Toast it but when I try to fix that image in the ImageView nothing happens.
So therefore, I would like to know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you use an adapter in wrong way. The adapter creates several views via `instantiateItem` method and you save the last one in field `v`, which is out of screen. By default `ViewPager` invokes `instantiateItem` for current position and near positions for caching.

As I understand your code, you should prefer to invoke `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`